# TCL spurious hang on exit

Tags: tcl, exec, stdout, freeze, stderr

Simple TCL hang

I use very simple TCL scripts to reproduce my problem. I run on windows 7 with activeTCL 8.6.4.1.
I use a simple batch file (loop.bat) that calls a tcl script (1.tcl) in a loop. That script then does a few "puts" and open another TCL shell to call another TCL script (2.tcl). That second script does two “puts”, one on stdout and one on stderr, then returns.

To reproduce the problem, I launch 16 instances of loop.bat and let it run for a whole night. When I come back in the morning, about half of the instances are stalled (hung).

Here is the code I use:

#### Loop.bat

```
@echo off
:loop
tclsh86 1.tcl
goto loop
```

#### 1.tcl

```
puts "start 1.tcl"
set error [catch {eval {exec tclsh86 2.tcl >@stdout 2>@stderr}} results]
puts "error = $error"
puts "results = $results"
puts "end 1.tcl"
return 0
```

#### 2.tcl

```
puts stdout "Print to stdout from 2.tcl."
puts stderr "Print to stderr from 2.tcl."
return 1
```

Comment: Does it happen if you use `exit` instead of `return`?

Comment: @DonalFellows : yes I have the exact same problem with exit but I read that the code for it was not following some MSDN guidelines and that maight be leading to hangs as I was experiencing. That is why I switched to cascaded returns instead of exit but I am still seeing it.

Comment: The `eval{...}` part looks like an extra step.  Unwrap it so its just `[catch {exec ...} resuts]`.

Comment: @wolfhammer You are perfectly right. The eval was remaining from my "real case". I removed it to know if it was linked in any way to my issue but I still have the same hang as before.

Answer (score 2):

> To reproduce the problem, I launch 16 instances of loop.bat and let it run for a whole night. When I come back in the morning, about half of the instances are stalled (hung).

There are new threads and file sockets created with iterations of 'exec', 'puts' addresses, and batch loops. If sockets or threads are created faster than they are recovered, the invoked 'sub' processes will eventually run out of available sockets or threads.

This may help explain: https://web.archive.org/web/20190217153445/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050729-14/?p=34773

Comment: I don't see how the link is relevan. It talks about thread stack size *within* a process. But in the question new processes are spawned, each with their own stack space. Something is obviously causing the problem, but I don't think the R Chen blog post explains it. Or I need more explanations, because I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

A solution might be to give Windows more control over the processes and use `start` to execute `tclsh86`:

```
@echo off
:loop
start /b /wait tclsh86 1.tcl
goto loop
```

This might solve the problem. '/b' suppresses creating a new console each time `tclsh86` is started.